# ListView binding

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding

I binded my column (Status) to value. But I need to show image for each values.
For example, Status column has values : 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1,0
So, for each values should correspond to the image. I want to see not value, but image!!!
How I can do this ? 
please help me.

```xml
<GridView>
    <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Style>
    </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>                            
    <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="0" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}" />
    <GridViewColumn Header="Login" Width="90" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Login}" />
    <GridViewColumn Width="65" Header="Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding UserStatus}">
    </GridViewColumn>

</GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to use the Itemtemplate

An example can be found here

http://huydinhpham.blogspot.com/2008/11/using-listvew-to-display-complex-data.html

Comment: ok. thanks. But If value can change in runtime, so than image should change too

Comment: Why this implementation did not work? My converter does not work
    
    <GridViewColumn Width="65" Header="Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding UserStatus}">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>